# using exposed and I want to use subquery by condition using caseWhenElse inside slice [kotlin, exposed]

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

```
val cor = TCorridor.slice(corridorNm).select{
    TCorridor.corridorId eq TFlightPathSegment.corridorId
} 

val corPo = TCorridorPoint.slice(pointNm).select{
    TCorridorPoint.pointId eq TFlightPathSegment.pointId
}

val pNm = SubQueryExpression<String>(corPo.alias(""))
val cNm = SubQueryExpression<String>(cor.alias(""))
```

> The reason why the alias is blank is that the alias is attached after the subquery in the case statement, causing an error.

```
val typeNm =
    Expression.build {
        case()
        .When((TFlightPathSegment.fltPathType eq "POINT"), pNm)
        .Else(cNm)
    }

val query = TFlightPathSegment
        .slice(TFlightPathSegment.fltPathId, TFlightPathSegment.sortOrd, TFlightPathSegment.fltPathType, TFlightPathSegment.pointId, TFlightPathSegment.corridorId
        , typeNm
).select { TFlightPathSegment.fltPathId eq fltPathId1 }
 .groupBy(TFlightPathSegment.fltPathId, TFlightPathSegment.sortOrd)
 .orderBy(TFlightPathSegment.sortOrd)
```

> The sql of the variable name query is output normally.
> Get the value of each field using query.map{}

```
query.map {
    
            println("case1 ---------- ")
            println(it) // if print it ↓
it = TFlightPathSegment.fliPathId = "", TFlightPathSegment.sortOrd = "", CASE WHEN TFlightPathSegment.fltPathType = "POINT" THEN (SELECT POINT_NM FROM TCorridorPoint where point_id = TFlightPathSegment.flt) = "POINT_NM"
}
```

> I want to get the value returned from the case statement
> if print it[typeNm] returned boolean Type
> but i want return value of subquery by condition
> What am I missing?

Comment: You've tagged this as `sql`, but the code looks more like Java (or something similar)... Could you add tags to say what language the code's actually written in?  I realise you're constructing queries for a DB using that language, but it looks like you're abstracted from actual SQL.

Comment: Apparently, kotlin, kotlin-exposed, and sql added three tags, but only sql seems to be applied.
tag added. thanks